# Mgo Aggregate pipline $not operator. Unknown top level operator

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mgo

I'm trying to create an aggregate pipeline using the Mgo driver. I keep running into the unknown top level operator $not issue for the following setup. I'm a beginner at using go and mongo. I'm creating this pipeline to filter out users that don't match a certain criteria such as that they are active. Is there any easier way to accomplish this?

```
 today := time.Now()   
 pipe2 := bson.M{"$match": bson.M{
                 "$not": []bson.M{
                         bson.M{StartDate: bson.M{"$gte": today}},
                         bson.M{EndDate: bson.M{"$lte": today}}}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$not` takes an object, not an array:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/

You have you change your query:

```
bson.M{"$match": 
   bson.M{StartDate: 
       bson.M{"$not": bson.M{"$gte": today, "$lte": today}}}}
```